# Add 1 more filter for divs in a JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to filter my divs by type of it (hotel/hostel), and the city where it is located. I have added filtering by type of property, but don't know how to add one more filter, and how to make it work good simultaneously. First filter looks like checkboxes, second is radiobuttons.
Divs:

```js
function change() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  var chekboxInputs = Array.from(checkboxes).map(a => a.querySelector('input'));
  var allAreUnselected = chekboxInputs.every(function(elem) {
    return !elem.checked;
  });
  if (allAreUnselected) {
    chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input) {
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item) {
        item.style.display = 'block';
      });
    });
  } else {
    chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input) {
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item) {
        item.style.display = input.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
      });
    });
  }
}
change();
```

```html
<div class="lviv hotel">
  <div class="hotel-info">
    <p>BonApart Deluxe Hotel</p>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Select Filters</h2>
<h3>Property Type</h3>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" rel="hotel" onchange="change()" />
  <p>Hotel</p>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" rel="hostel" onchange="change()" />
  <p>Hostel</p>
</div>

<h3>City</h3>
<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="cities"> Kyiv</div>
<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="cities"> Lviv</div>
<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="cities"> Tokyo</div>
```

Comment: The attribute selector is `[attr="val"]` not `.attr`. Reverfiy your `querySelectorAll` for `rel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of both the selections separately and finally decide what to show. `type` is a kind of `OR` operation as it is allowed to be one of many options. `city` is must have a property in your div classes.

The following code will work as you expect with both checkboxes and radio buttons. It can be extended as you want.

```
let types = [];
let city = undefined;

function change() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
  types = Array.from(checkboxes)
    .filter((a) => a.querySelector("input").checked)
    .map((a) => a.querySelector("input").getAttribute("rel"));

  var radioButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("radio");
  city = Array.from(radioButtons)
    .find((a) => a.querySelector("input").checked)
    ?.querySelector("input")
    ?.getAttribute("value");

  if (types == [] && city == undefined) {
    // no filters selected
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item")).forEach(function (
      item
    ) {
      item.style.display = "block";
    });
  } else {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item")).forEach(function (
      item
    ) {
      let itemTags = item
        .getAttribute("class")
        .split(" ")
        .filter((item) => item !== "item");

      let visible = true;

      if (city) {
        visible = itemTags.indexOf(city) >= 0;
      }

      if (types.length > 0) {
        visible =
          visible && types.some((item) => itemTags.indexOf(item) >= 0);
      }

      item.style.display = visible ? "block" : "none";
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="lviv hotel item">
      <div class="hotel-info">
        <p>BonApart Deluxe Hotel</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tokyo hostel item">
      <div class="hostel-info">
        <p>Hostel in Tokyo</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h2>Select Filters</h2>

    <h3>Property Type</h3>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" rel="hotel" onchange="change()" />
      <label>Hotel</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" rel="hostel" onchange="change()" />
      <label>Hostel</label>
    </div>

    <h3>City</h3>
    <div class="radio">
      <input
        type="radio"
        value="kyiv"
        id="Kyiv"
        name="city"
        onchange="change()"
      /><label for="Kyiv">Kyiv</label><br />
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input
        type="radio"
        value="lviv"
        id="Lviv"
        name="city"
        onchange="change()"
      /><label for="Lviv">Lviv</label><br />
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input
        type="radio"
        value="tokyo"
        id="Tokyo"
        name="city"
        onchange="change()"
      /><label for="Tokyo">Tokyo</label><br />
    </div>

    <script>
      let types = [];
      let city = undefined;

      function change() {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
        types = Array.from(checkboxes)
          .filter((a) => a.querySelector("input").checked)
          .map((a) => a.querySelector("input").getAttribute("rel"));

        var radioButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("radio");
        city = Array.from(radioButtons)
          .find((a) => a.querySelector("input").checked)
          ?.querySelector("input")
          ?.getAttribute("value");

        if (types == [] && city == undefined) {
          // no filters selected
          Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item")).forEach(function (
            item
          ) {
            item.style.display = "block";
          });
        } else {
          Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item")).forEach(function (
            item
          ) {
            let itemTags = item
              .getAttribute("class")
              .split(" ")
              .filter((item) => item !== "item");

            let visible = true;

            if (city) {
              visible = itemTags.indexOf(city) >= 0;
            }

            if (types.length > 0) {
              visible =
                visible && types.some((item) => itemTags.indexOf(item) >= 0);
            }

            item.style.display = visible ? "block" : "none";
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that I have added a common CSS class ("item") to all the items you gonna either show or hide, to make it easier to select them easily.

Comment: @Anna, check this out !!